# Read ajax value into another javascript file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have  a JS file where I read variable "`category`" and I need to get this value and pass to another js file.

JS file who contains variable "`category`":

```
function FleetCompletePopulate(url, listname, listname2, target) {

    var eng = false;
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        eng = true;
    }


    $(function () {
      $.ajax({                       
         url: "https://myapi.mycompany.com/api/apiweb/gettipoembarcacion"  ,
         async: false,
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             completeFleetCat(data, target, eng, url, listname2);
          },
           error: function (data) {
              failureFleetCat(data, target);
            }
           });

    });

}

function completeFleetCat(data, target, eng, url, listname2) {
    var items = data;
    console.log(items)
    var menu = "";
    var cat = "";
    var title = "";
    var descrip = "";
    for (item in items) {
        if (eng) {
            cat = replaceAll("'", "\'", replaceAll(" ", "_", items[item].English.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));
            title = items[item].English;
            descrip = items[item].Description;
        }
        else {
            cat = replaceAll("'", "\'", replaceAll(" ", "_", items[item].Title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));
            title = items[item].Title;
            descrip = items[item].Descripcion;
        }
        if (descrip == null)
            descrip = "";
        menu += "<div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading' role='tab' id='heading" + cat + "'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-10'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#" + cat + "' aria-expanded='true' aria-controls='" + cat + "'><em class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></em>&nbsp;<span class='th2'>" + title + "</span></a><br />" + descrip + "</div><div class='col-md-2' style='border:0px solid red'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#" + cat + "' aria-expanded='true' aria-controls='" + cat + "'><img src='" + items[item].Imagen+ "' class='img-responsive' /></a></div></div></div><div id=" + cat + " class='panel-collapse collapse in' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='heading" + cat + "'></div></div>";
    }
    $(target).html(menu);
    for (item in items) {
        if (eng) {
            FleetPopulate(url, listname2, items[item].English);
        }
        else {

            FleetPopulate(url, listname2, items[item].Title);
        }
    }

    $("a[aria-expanded='true']").click(function () {
        $(this).find("em").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
    });

}

function failureFleetCat(data, target) {
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga las categorias. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}

function FleetPopulate(url, listname, category) {

    var eng = false;
    var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Imagen,Enlace,Especificaciones,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title&$filter=Categoria/Title eq '" + category + "'";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        queryGallery = "$select=Title,Imagen,Enlace,Specifications,Categoria/English&$expand=Categoria/English&$filter=Categoria/English eq '" + category + "'";
        eng = true;
    }
    var lang = "Espanol";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        lang = "English";
    }




     $(function () {
      $.ajax({                       
         url: "https://myapi.mycompany.com/api/webapi/getembarcaciones?idioma="+ lang +"&categoria=" +category   ,
         async: false,
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
              completeFleet(data, "#" + replaceAll("'", "\'", replaceAll(" ", "_", category.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''))), eng);
          },
           error: function (data) {
             failureFleet(data, category);
            }
           });

    });

}

function completeFleet(data, target, eng) {
    var items = data;
    console.log(items);
    var prefix = "<div class='row'>";
    var sufix = "</div>";
    var menu = "<div class='col-md-4'>";
    var cat = "";
    var spec = "";
    var counter = 0;
    var obj = null;
    for (item in items) {
        spec = "";
        if (counter == 1) {

            menu += "</div><div class='col-md-4'>";
            counter = 0;
        }
        if (eng) {
        if(items[item].Specifications == null){
        console.log("Something come null"); 
        }
            obj = JSON.parse(items[item].Specifications);
            for (var key in obj) {
                spec += "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 ftBottomSeparator'><span class=' t10'>" + key + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='t06' style='float:right;'>" + obj[key] + "</span></div></div>";
            }
            menu += "<div class='row ftContainerOut'><div class='col-md-12 ftContainer'><div class='row ftHeader'><div class='col-xs-9 t09'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><div class='col-xs-3 text-right'></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-6' style='padding-top:10px'><img src='" + items[item].Imagen + "' class='img-responsive img-center' style='border:0px solid blue; max-width:150px;max-height:120px;' /></div><div class='col-md-6'>" + spec + "</div></div></div></div>";
        } else {

          if(items[item].Especificaciones == null){
        console.log("Something come null");
        }else{
        console.log("Nothing comes null")
        }



    obj = JSON.parse(items[item].Especificaciones);
        if(items[item].Especificaciones == null){

            for (var key in obj) {
                spec += "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 ftBottomSeparator'><span class=' t10'>" + key + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='t06'  style='float:right;'>" + obj[key] + "</span></div></div>";
            }}else if(items[item].Especificaciones != null){
            for (var key in obj) {
                spec += "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 ftBottomSeparator'><span class=' t10'>" + key + "</span>&nbsp;<span class='t06'  style='float:right;'>" + obj[key] + "</span></div></div>";
}
            }

            menu += "<div class='row ftContainerOut'><div class='col-md-12 ftContainer'><div class='row ftHeader'><div class='col-xs-9 t09'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><div class='col-xs-3 text-right'></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-6' style='padding-top:10px'><img src='" + items[item].Imagen+ "' class='img-responsive img-center' style='border:0px solid blue; max-width:150px;max-height:120px;' /></div><div class='col-md-6'>" + spec + "</div></div></div></div>";
        }
        counter++;
    }
    $(target).html("<div class='panel-body'><div class='container-fluid'>" + prefix + menu + sufix + "</div></div>");

}

function failureFleet(data, target) {
    console.log(data);
    $(target).text("Ocurrió un error en la carga la sección parallax. Por favor revise la consola para más información");
}

function replaceAll(find, replace, string) {
    return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}
function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

As you can see in my function I call variable  "category" like this:

```
 function FleetPopulate(url, listname, category)
```

So in my new JS file I need to get this variable to call into my url so I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    GetFlotaInfo();

});


function GetFlotaInfo(){

        var lang = "Espanol";
        if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
            lang = "English";  
        } 

        var page = window.location.pathname.replace("/SitePages/", "");

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://myapi-qa.mycompany.com/api/webapi/getflotainfo?
idioma=" + lang + "&pagina=" + page + "&categoria=" + category,
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                GetFlotaInfoSuccess(data);
                //alert("Cargo con exito");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                //failureGlobal(data);
                alert("Error al cargar la información de flota");
            }
        })

    }

    function GetFlotaInfoSuccess(data)
    {
        completeFleet(data.Flota, "#divFlota");
    }
```

I want to get ""category" into my url parameter, I try this but isn´t works

```
url: "https://myapi-qa.mycompany.com/api/webapi/getflotainfo?
idioma=" + lang + "&pagina=" + page + "&categoria=" + category
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Set a variable on the namespace you use, or are all these functions global?

Comment: Not are global, I want to use only in one aspx, where I supposed to set variable? into FleetPopulate? @Shilly

Comment: On the namespace all the functions belong to, so in this case, create a global variable on window. But from what I read, the category comes from the data fetched by fleetCompletePopulate, so I think you'll need to turn around your logic a bit. You can't really access the category name coming from the JSON file before you fetched that JSON file, so you probably have to call FleetCompletePopulate before calling GetFlotaInfo.

Comment: So in my new js I just call  FleetCompletePopulate() then GetFlotaInfo() and I can access to variable? @Shilly

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example--a few dozen lines, perhaps.